# Fit a shape enclosing data points

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting

I have some data points as shown in the image:
[image]

I want to fit a curve that encloses all these data points, e.g. an ellipse or a circle. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). You can use [`ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) from `scipy` module.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

hull = ConvexHull(points)
plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])
for simplex in hull.simplices:
    plt.plot(points[simplex, 0], points[simplex, 1], 'k-')
```

```
>>> points
#            x             y
array([[ 1.85804999, -0.05672655],
       [-1.26377587, -0.71670609],
       [ 1.20926884, -0.90475264],
       ...,
       [-0.90567066, -0.84883138],
       [-0.43970639,  1.84684422],
       [ 0.19636511,  1.93878809]])

>>> hull.vertices
array([413, 129, 655, 254, 841, 793, 321, 526, 570, 695, 668, 601, 824,
        97, 137, 711, 764, 880, 645,  78, 170, 767, 242, 400, 847, 279,
       693], dtype=int32)

>>> points[hull.vertices]
array([[-1.41519105,  1.40697935],
       [-1.82809455,  0.76082381],
       [-1.96558532,  0.33289305],
       [-1.98560143, -0.01191735],
       [-1.94680891, -0.44858819],
       [-1.92640504, -0.50545949],
       [-1.82801696, -0.72696817],
       [-1.62541354, -1.10389154],
       [-0.81276609, -1.81667984],
       [-0.5230336 , -1.91088401],
       [-0.16741267, -1.9816704 ],
       [ 0.60681346, -1.85569449],
       [ 0.97014715, -1.73968032],
       [ 1.34722226, -1.46198943],
       [ 1.80922099, -0.83972869],
       [ 1.86933042, -0.62334995],
       [ 1.94523674, -0.29988429],
       [ 1.88851458,  0.51313387],
       [ 1.78142205,  0.85649355],
       [ 1.71284948,  0.99370767],
       [ 1.2998368 ,  1.51082726],
       [ 0.88852111,  1.74722282],
       [ 0.50725689,  1.8652817 ],
       [ 0.17148352,  1.95374732],
       [ 0.04487085,  1.98223443],
       [-0.74854329,  1.8364107 ],
       [-1.05242057,  1.69470583]])
```

[image]